# Creating nested dictionary

Tags: python, nested, ordereddictionary

I want to create dictionary like this

***{"index":{"_index":"caba", "_type":"_doc", "_id": "6"}}

{"olc-id" : 8994267,"location" : {"lat" : -34.5468357428716,"lon" : -58.4481124350856}}

{"index":{"_index":"caba", "_type":"_doc", "_id": "5"}}

{"olc-id" : 9004108,"location" : {"lat" : -34.6555189999163,"lon" : -58.4479851369256}}

{"index":{"_index":"caba", "_type":"_docs", "_id": "4"}}

{"olc-id" : 9005976,"location" : {"lat" : -34.6329681367607,"lon" : -58.3912744601535}}***

As I am new to python, I'm facing trouble in it.
My Data File is like this:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzqXr.png)
I tried this:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

index = defaultdict(Counter)
reader = csv.reader("file.csv")
#code_index = 0
#id = 1
for row in reader:
    if row and len(row) >= 2:
        _index = "caba"
        _type = "_doc"
        _id = row
        index[_index][_type] += 1
print (index)
```

So what changes should I make?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add sample contents of your file.csv in the question

Comment: This question is already answered many times. Example by list comprehension is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50279889/8333806).